# Artifactory: Local Pypi repos 'slow' after upgrade to new artifactory 5.10.3 with new Pypi support

Tags: python, pip, artifactory, pypi

we updated our artifactoy to the newest version 5.10.3 to support the pypi update.

after this update we experience some really slow `pip install --upgrade` times.
`pip install` is running fine.

I was able to pinpoint this slower runs to the local pypi repositiory on the artifactory.

The official pypi and the cached remote pypi on the artifactory were fast.

But the virtual pypi (remote und local pypi) and if i only add the local pypi via `--extra-index-url` were both slow

Some versions, maybe we have some issues there:

- python 2.7 and 3.5
- pip 9.0.1 and 10.01
- artifactory 5.10.3

Run with official Pypi only:

`pip install -U -r requirements.txt  1.21s user 0.08s system 99% cpu 1.296 total`

Run with local pypi as extra-index-url:

`pip install -U -r requirements.txt  1.51s user 0.09s system 8% cpu 19.658 total`

And with the virtual pypi:

`pip install -U -r requirements.txt  1.57s user 0.10s system 4% cpu 38.573 total`

Unfortunately i don't have and time before the update.

some ideas?

Comment: The problem exists in 5.8.9, 5.9.5, & 5.10.3 (any version containing the required changes for the Pypi endpoint change.) I've test a dozen other versions, on average those mentioned above are about 4.5 times slower. If you have the ability to make a ticket in jfrogs jira you should do that.

Comment: Jira Ticket: RTFACT-16513

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was fixed in the Artifactory Release 5.10.4

The corresponding Ticket is https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-16513

> Degradation happens on Derby DB in case node_props table has many entries, due to a changed DB query introduced at RTFACT-15433

After the upgrade, the pypi repos will be *fast* again.

Answer (score 2):

[Artifactory 5.10.4](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Release+Notes#ReleaseNotes-Artifactory5.10.4) corrected this problem for us--we're seeing an 8x increase in performance.

Comment: Don't create an answer to bypass the restrictions on new users. Contribute to the community and you'll be able to comment, vote, set bounties, etc.